Jaspersoft Localization (through JSON as Input)
So I have set up my Jaspersoft localization, which is working fine from inside the report. But now I want to control the language from outside of the Jaspersoft, through the JSON, which I also use to give data input to the File. I have tried something like creating a field to extract the language code out of the JSON and add it to the Ressource Bundle of myreport, like this, but it isnt working yet.

The Ressource Bundles I have look like this and are working fine, when I manully change the path to either _en or _de.

I've tried it like this Ressource Bundles: Localization/LocaleReport_$F{language}
